# TableView did not work when exe file

Tags: python, tableview, pyqt4, exe

I made an application that uses `sqlite3` and `PyQt4`. Until I convert my app to exe, `tableView` work properly. But then it did not work since it did not save changes or show changes. I used `cxFreeze` to convert my file. What's the problem here?
I also want to add that i am using this modules;

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlQueryModel,QSqlDatabase,QSqlQuery
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sqlite3 as sql
import os, time
```

And I guess the problem is `QtSql`, maybe? Because It handle the table and db things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791868/cx-freeze-qodbc-driver-not-loaded guys this is the answer

Comment: We must add sqldrivers file into the exe file.